# php error when submitting form on the same page

Tags: php, form-submit

> my problem is that when i submitting form on the same page i am getting
>   this error :  Undefined index: myname  on line 46 name is empty , i don't know what is exact problem , can any one resolve  this issue ?

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
    name : <input type="text" name="myname">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{
    $name=$_POST['myname'];
    if(empty($name)){
        echo "name is empty";
    }
    else{
        echo  "name is $name";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I run your code to my machine. It's working good.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes duplicate ? i am not getting you

Comment: @SumonMahmud really ? but on my machine i am getting the error i am not getting it why its happening

Comment: remove caches from your browser and try again.